# Is there a case in which Green's theorem will not work, but Stokes theorem will?

Tags: stokes-theorem

I "know" that you can use Green's theorem to integrate over a region bounded by a  closed loop.  But this is only if the vector field has continuous first partial derivatives inside the region.

So I thought that Stokes theorem allowed us to avoid the discontinuity in the 2D region by "going over it" using a 3D surface instead.  Now that I have done numerous homework problems, I'm thinking I got this all wrong.  It seems Stokes theorem is just a really hard way to doing Green's theorem.

Why would anyone use Stokes theorem instead of Green's theorem?  Stokes is just more work!

Comment: Stokes' Theorem is a much more general result that is extended to n-dimensional spaces. Also, it's so elegant...

Comment: Green's theorem is a very special case of Stokes's theorem, for a curve embedded in the plane (and is often derived as such). Stokes's theorem applies to a general surface in three-dimensional space. All such theorems require some sort of continuity of derivatives in their derivations.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!  I guess that's really the answer.  That is, you're always using Stokes theorem and it always boils down to a simple case called Green's theorem.  At least I can't seem to find an example in which the all of Stokes is used.  Every problem I do can be solved using Green's theorem.